# Is there an open source library to serve files over the net? (with complete ui)

Tags: share

im currently working on a closed network (security reasons) and i wish to have a website which will serve many usefull downloads.

Is there an open-source library which i can use to upload such thing? with complete ui and functionality?

[priority for javascript libs]

thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a fileserver, webserver, or network mount?

Comment: Are you running windows or linux?

Comment: If you are looking to serve things locally on a small network, a network share may be best

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows and looking for a full UI solution, you should check out Filezilla Server https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

If you don't mind using the command line:

If you are looking for a webserver, I suggest apache2/httpd webserver https://httpd.apache.org/

For FTP I recommend ProFTPd http://www.proftpd.org/

And for Network share I suggest using NFS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System

If you are looking to serve things locally on a small network, a network share may be best